# React memo not rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In parent I have two instances of media ad on same page with different props, since parent page interacts with api we have multiple renders and my functional component in memoised to avoid re renders, but the problem I have is `MediaAd` component is not showing up in the page. If I remove memo it shows up but with rendering twice.

```
<MediaAd
   coupons={this.props.coupons}
   mediaScroll={this.props.mediaScroll}
   isMobile="false"
   userAgent={this.props.userAgent}
   nonce={this.props.nonce}
   adPlacement="top"
/>

<MediaAd
   coupons={this.props.coupons}
   mediaScroll={this.props.mediaScroll}
   isMobile="false"
   userAgent={this.props.userAgent}
   nonce={this.props.nonce}
   adPlacement="bottom"
/>
```

And the functional component is below.

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';

const MediaAd = ((props) => {
  const adId = getAddContainer({ ...props });
  return adId !== null ? (
    <div className="mediaWrapper">
      <div className="mediaAd">
        <div id={adId}>
          <script nonce={props.nonce.nonce}>{displayMediaAd({ ...props, adId })}</script>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : null;
});
export default memo(MediaAd);
```

Comment: Can you provide a CodeSandbox with this issue?

Comment: First thing first, are you using React v16.6.0 and above?

Comment: Yes I am using React v16.6.0.